# Pandas: Convert int columnt to Date column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

```
Day GrocerySales
1   8418.59
2   8447.47
3   8336.49
4   8579.17
5   8524.31
6   8623.5
7   8320.11
8   8313.53
9   8461.34
10  8497.24
11  8674.65
12  8354.63
13  8526.67
14  8767.31
15  8689.53
```

i have my data in above format.

i need to convert Day number column to datetime Column to perform time series analysis.

can someone please help me with this.

Comment: did you try anything? what's the date of day 1?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps add the days to the beginning fo the year `datetime.date(2020, 1, 1) + dateutil.relativedelta(days=x)`

Comment: No their no date provided for Day 1 number in dataset..only above 2 columns in dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then you use the `origin` parameter to set the origin date and set the `unit` parameter to `d` to use your integer values as day values. Here the code

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = { 'Day' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'GrocerySales' : [8418.59,8447.47, 8336.49, 8579.17, 8524.31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], unit='d',origin=pd.Timestamp('2020-05-08'))
```

Output:

```
    Day   GrocerySales      date
0   1     8418.59           2020-05-09
1   2     8447.47           2020-05-10
2   3     8336.49           2020-05-11
3   4     8579.17           2020-05-12
4   5     8524.31           2020-05-13
```